# Firefox addon compatibility

Tags: firefox-addon, compatibility

```
<em:targetApplication>
  <Description>
    <em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
    <em:maxVersion>3.6.16</em:maxVersion>
  </Description>
</em:targetApplication>
```

the only declaration who get the compatibility of some firefox addon or are there any other?

I'm trying for creating my first extension whith the declaration shown. When i install my addon firefox told me that the extension is not compatible with where installed version of the browser (3.6)

Comment: Is this the only code you have in `install.rdf`? I hope not.

Comment: You can post comments on answers to your own question.  Please don't add new answers that don't answer the question.

Comment: Posting your entire install.rdf would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need the ID of the application. E.g. for Firefox:

```
<em:targetApplication>
    <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>1.5</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>3.6.16</em:maxVersion>
    </Description>
</em:targetApplication>
```

**Update:** It is difficult to tell why it does not work without seeing all the code. I suggest you read [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/building_an_extension).

Comment: Ok, i've added the line you show me but it does not works.

Can javascript (for example) or other elements interfere with addon compatibility?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that you should avoid specifying a particular maxVersion unless there's some weird reason why your extension isn't compatible with a security update. Instead you should use something along the lines of `3.6.*`